# Using d3.js brush as a filter for SlickGrid

Tags: filter, d3.js, slickgrid, brush

There's an excellent example of [SlickGrid and d3.js](http://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/examples/slickgrid.html) being used together. I'm trying to adapt this visualisation for my own purposes, but am finding the example too complex to break down. These examples seem to dominate all the search results on the subject, so I'm struggling to find something simpler to learn from.

I would like to take a standard chart (scatter plot/bar chart/etc.), apply brushes and display the filtered results in a data table. I've successfully used dc.js to do this (works out of the box), but my actual data has tens of thousands of rows...making SlickGrid the preferential choice.

Here is a [link](http://jsfiddle.net/y4N98/1/) to a jsFiddle showing what I'm trying to achieve. The brush can identify what data has been "brushed" (applying a class change for appearance's sake), **but I don't how to pass the IDs of this data to SlickGrid in order to update the grid**. In the jsFiddle, I'm trying to use gridUpdate(d) like the original parallel co-ordinates example did...no success.

```
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "brush")
    .call(d3.svg.brush().x(x).y(y)
    .on("brushstart", brushstart)
    .on("brush", brushmove)
    .on("brushend", brushend));

function brushmove() {
    var e = d3.event.target.extent();

    rectData.classed("selected", function(d, i) {
    if ( e[1][1] >= d.id && e[0][1] <= d.id && x(e[0][0]) <= x(d.Date) && x(e[1][0]) >= x(d.Date) ) 
        { gridUpdate(d); return true; } 
    else 
        { return false; };
});
```

I've tried many iterations, but I can't quite figure out what dataView wants as an input...

```
function gridUpdate(data) {
    dataView.beginUpdate();
    dataView.setItems(data);
    dataView.endUpdate();
};
```

Any help would be much appreciated, I've struggled with the documentation on SlickGrid and have finally gotten to the point where I need to ask for help!

Comment: How are those IDs stored? If they aren't explicit parts of the objects, maybe you could make them?

Comment: I create the IDs as part of the CSV parsing (using i for "id").

I think I have something that's working relatively well, although it's not particularly efficient.

The elements within the brush all receive a CSS class change (they're changed to "selected"), so I'm running `gridUpdate(d3.selectAll(".selected").data());`, which passes what look like the correct values to dataView.

Comment: Updated fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/y4N98/2/)

Comment: It seems to be working fine. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: The original wasn't - I think this minor modification is probably suitable for an answer, unless anyone can point out any major inefficiencies in it. Lars, you've been particularly good at checking some of my recent questions; thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Do you want to post the answer so that other people looking for the same can find it?

Comment: Will do - I'm going to comment the jsFiddle example a bit because I've spent hours searching for similar stuff and therefore want it to be clear for others. Thanks again.